# HTML line-height unwanted gaps

Tags: html, css, gaps-in-visuals

Line-height causes gaps between images and other elements but changing its value to 0 makes any text impossible to read, is there any easy fix for that?

Imagine some repeatable DOM element like a shadow, how would you erase gap between this element and anything that is above (may be an image, div, span, button, form)?

Setting class for this .shadow and giving it line-height of 0 of course doesn't work as line-height works a bit differently.

I made 3 images, the first one shows what I'm talking about, the second one fixes it, the third one shows how the second one in fact destroyed the whole layout:

http://jsfiddle.net/J5PLf/

I'm thinking about something like:

```
body {
   line-height: 0;
}

p {
   line-height: 1.2em;
}
```

But I guess it's a bit risky, what if there will be some free text not within

tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't mess with the `line-height` propety, and set `display:block` at the images.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J5PLf/1/

```
#example1, #example2, #example3 {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}
img {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you I didn't know that. I'm not sure how it will affect my site's layout but seems excellent at the moment.

Comment: Elements with `display:block;` won't tolerate non-floating elements at the same line. If you ever need a good source, have a look at the Mozilla Developer's Network, eg: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/display

Comment: Thanks, you are saving my life.